# Slidetoggle hide previous div

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Thank you in advance for your time!
This is my set up and Id like previously clicked divs to hide before showing the new div with slidetoggle.

CSS:

```
.waxing {
    display: none;
}

.facials {
    display: none;
}

.bodywraps {
   display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="heroIcons">
    <div class="button waxingButton">
        <p>view prices</p>
    </div>

    <div class="button facialsButton">
        <p>view prices</p>
    </div>

    <div class="button bodywrapsButton">
        <p>view prices</p>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="section services">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="waxing">
            <p>content that I want to slidetoggle</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="section services">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="facials">
            <p>content that I want to slidetoggle</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="section services">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bodywraps">
            <p>content that I want to slidetoggle</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".heroIcons .waxingButton").click(function(){
    $(".waxing").slideToggle(1500);
});

$(".heroIcons .facialsButton").click(function(){
    $(".facials").slideToggle(1500);
});

$(".heroIcons .bodywrapsButton").click(function(){
    $(".bodywraps").slideToggle(1500);
});
```

This all works just fine, but Id like it to close the previously opened divs with when I click to open a different div

Comment: The HTML doesn't include the classes in your CSS?

Comment: I saw that I left it out. Just added it, thank you!

Comment: Could you use something like in the fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/dymc48ye/

Comment: UI-wise - use the `<button type="button">` element with descriptive aria labels instead of `<div>` elements *as-buttons*... https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/accordion/accordion.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid code repetition as much as you can (*DRY principle*).

Here is a little bit refactored markup but you can add any number of buttons and sections without adding more JS code:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var className = $(this).data('button')
  
  $('.content').hide()
  $('.' + className).slideToggle(1500);
});
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer
}

.content {
  display: none;
  background: honeydew;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button" data-button="waxing">
  <p>view prices</p>
</div>

<div class="button" data-button="facials">
  <p>view prices</p>
</div>

<div class="button" data-button="bodywraps">
  <p>view prices</p>
</div>

<div class="content waxing">waxing PRICES</div>
<div class="content facials">facials PRICES</div>
<div class="content bodywraps">bodywraps PRICES</div>
```

Comment: Since you're correctly suggesting to stay *DRY*,  a Utility class like `.u-hidden {display: none;}` would complete your nice example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Excellent point! But since all the `.content` elements have to be hidden we don't even need a utility class - it's even better to add `display: none` to their main rule.

Comment: Even better, yes, unless `.content` might clash being a too general className - therefore a more specific selector would be better, but yeah, OP got the idea.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this - it should hide the open dropdowns before opening the one you click on (you will want to adjust the speeds on .hide)

```
$(".heroIcons .waxingButton").click(function() {
$(".bodywraps").hide(1500);
$(".facials").hide(1500);
$(".waxing").slideToggle(1500);
});

$(".heroIcons .facialsButton").click(function() {
$(".bodywraps").hide(1500);
$(".waxing").hide(1500);
$(".facials").slideToggle(1500);
});

$(".heroIcons .bodywrapsButton").click(function() {
$(".waxing").hide(1500);
$(".facials").hide(1500);
$(".bodywraps").slideToggle(1500);
});
```